# How to Create Client Workspace using Perforce command-line on Wndows

Tags: perforce

I am trying to create client workspace using cmd on windows, please suggest.

Comment: ..and then what happens after you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

By default your client workspace has the same name as the client machine.  If you want to change it, run:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=whatever_client_name_you_want
```

Once you have your P4CLIENT name set, run:

```
p4 client
```

to create and edit the client specification.